# How do I create the sequence 1 12 123

Tags: r

I am doing some R code practice and is wanting to generate some specific sequence.

I want to use the function seq() to generate sequence, which I have tried the following code, but it seems like character is not available in seq()

```
n <- c(1 : 100)
seq(from = 1, to = n )
```

I expect the sequence to be 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4.... However, this code isn't able to work

Answer (score 7):

In the following way:

```
sequence(1:100)
```

`sequence` works by creating a vector from `1` until the number passed to `sequence()` Since this function is vectorized, you can insert multiple numbers at once with `c(1:100)` at get the necessary output.